# Count number of ordered pairs of integers a,b such that $ab$ divides $a+b+p $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Problem:**

For a given value of $p$  where $p$ is a prime,
$a,b \in \mathbb{I}$ and $a,b \in [1,p-1]$

We are to count ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab | (a+b+p)$

Since some users are confused with the problem statement I want to re-emphasize that the value of p is given or constant. You don't need to solve for all values of p, you just need to solve for one particular value of p. You can assume p to be any large prime and explian your approch if that makes it simpler. Lets say $p = 719$, then you are to count ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab | (a+b+719)$ and $a,b \in [1,718]$

**My thoughts so far:**

for $a=b$ case I can try out and see $a=b=1$ is the only solution.
So for all other ordered pairs $a \ne b$

For other a=1 cases ie 1 < b,

$b | 1+b+p$

$ \iff  1+b+p=kb$

$ \iff  b(k-1)=p+1$

so number of factors of $p+1$ might be the solution with $a=1$

(WLOG assuimg $a<b$), Another thing that I am observing is for a given `b` there exists exactly one (or none) values of `a`.(not proved yet) -------(1)

(WLOG assuimg $a<b$), Another thing that I am observing is whenever a solution exists , a is reatively small, possibly less than  $\sqrt{p}$(not proved yet) --------(2)

incorporating the observation(2) I can calculate in $p\sqrt{p}$ time.

**Update adding to maximusfastidiousirreverence's answer:**

Even though @maximusfastidiousirreverence's approach looks cool at outset but while implementing I realised traversing all k $\in [1,p-1]$ gets me to same $p\sqrt{p}$ time.

valid $k$ is dense in $[1,\sqrt{p}]$ but very sparse in range $[\sqrt{p},p+2]$ . So it would be stupid to iterative for every $k \in [\sqrt{p}+1,p-1]$ . We can iterate for every k till $\sqrt{p}$ and Beyond $\sqrt{p}$ we can traverse more intelligently. We can do something like traverse every value of a $\in [1,\sqrt{p}]$ and retrieve the corresponding k. Following is the proof why it should work

(WLOG assuimg $a<b$),

$(ka−1)<(kb−1)<kp+1$

let $a=\sqrt p+d_1$

$ \iff b=\sqrt{p}+d_2$ where $d_1<d_2 $
$ \iff (k\sqrt{p}+kd_1−1)(k\sqrt{p}+kd_2−1)=kp+1$

$ \iff (k\sqrt{p} + kd_1 − 1) (k\sqrt{p} + kd_2 − 1) = kp + 1 $
$ \iff  k\sqrt{p}(k\sqrt{p} + kd_2 − 1)  +kd_1(k\sqrt{p} + kd_2 − 1) - (k\sqrt{p} + kd_2 − 1) = kp + 1 $
$ \iff  k\sqrt{p}k\sqrt{p} + k\sqrt{p}kd_2 − k\sqrt{p}  +kd_1k\sqrt{p} + kd_1kd_2 − kd_1 - k\sqrt{p} - kd_2 + 1 = kp + 1 $
$ \iff  k^2p + k^2\sqrt{p}d_2 − k\sqrt{p}  +k^2d_1\sqrt{p} + k^2d_1d_2 − kd_1 - k\sqrt{p} - kd_2 + 1 = kp + 1 $
$ \iff  k^2p + k^2\sqrt{p}d_2 − k\sqrt{p}  +k^2d_1\sqrt{p} + k^2d_1d_2 − kd_1 - k\sqrt{p} - kd_2 = kp $
$ \iff  k^2p + k^2\sqrt{p}(d_1+d_2) + k^2d_1d_2 = 2k\sqrt p + k(d_1+d_2) + kp $
$ \iff  kp + k\sqrt p(d_1+d_2) + kd_1d_2 =  p + 2\sqrt p + (d_1+d_2) $
$ \iff  k = [p + 2\sqrt p + (d_1+d_2)]/[p + \sqrt p(d_1+d_2) +d_1d_2] $

To maximise $k$ we minimize the denom,i.e put $d_1=0,d_2=1$
$ \iff k = (p + 2\sqrt{p} + 1)/(p + \sqrt{p} +1) $
$ \iff k = 1 + \sqrt{p}/(p + \sqrt{p} +1) $
$ \iff a>\sqrt p, 1 <=k_{max}<2$
$ \iff a>\sqrt p, k_{max}=1$

So all the higher(ie $ \gt\sqrt{p}$) values of k are generated when $a \le \sqrt{p}$

$ a+b+p=kab$
$ \iff  (ka-1)b=(a+p)$

Now we will factorise(a+p) for each $a \le \sqrt{p}$

Time complexity for this part will be $O(\sqrt{p}.p^{1/4})$=$O(p^{3/4})$

Time complexity for $k\le\sqrt{p}$ part will be $O(\sqrt{p}.(\sqrt{p}.p)^{1/4})$=$O(p^{7/8})$

Net time complecity will be $O(p^{7/8})$

**EDIT**:

Just realised $k \le p$ part is not required, factorising $(a+p)$ is enough as all those cases for lesser values of $k$ are also being covered in this too. So we can solve in $O(p^{3/4})$

Comment: Context for this problem? Knowing whether it is a homework exercise would be helpful. It does depend on the prime I believe, I am not positive yet if neatly.

Comment: @Mike sure it does depend on the prime. go ahead with a resonably large prime of your choice to explain yout approach. the idea behind writing it as p is to generalise it as an algorithm. No its  not a homework problem. I have been researching on some stuff(not hardcore maths related) where such forms have come up.

Comment: I just ran a simple brute force loop with pari-gp and no pattern seems to jump out at me. You should elaborate on what stuff you've been researching where the forms have come up in your question, might make me or other people more interested in spending time on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an integer $\quad k\quad$ such that $\quad k=\frac{a+b+p}{ab}\quad$ then

$kab=a+b+p \iff kab-a-b=p \iff k^2ab-k(a+b)= kp$
$$(ka-1)(kb-1)=kp+1$$

essentially two free variables.  With increasing size of the prime $\quad p\quad$ there will be more and more solutions.  Splitting the RHS into two divisors, you may have
$$\begin{cases}a=\frac{d_1+1}k\\b=\frac{d_2+1}k\end{cases}\quad \text{such that}\quad kp+1=d_1d_2$$
And you're limited to the amount of divisors of $\quad kp+1\quad$ and whether or not $\quad k\quad$ divides the divisor plus 1.  You do always have $\quad k=1\quad$ in which case
$$(a,b)=(d_1+1,d_2+1)\qquad \text{such that}\quad d_1d_2=p+1$$
but to number the solutions for each prime is random

Note $(a,b)=(1,1)\quad$ will always be a solution, giving the maximum value for $\quad k:\quad k=p+2\quad$ so you can say $\quad k\in [1,p+2]$

Comment: on RHS we keep increasing $k$ till when? do you have an upper bound?

Comment: setting $a=b=1$ would give the max value for $k: \quad k=p+2$

Comment: Can you clarify on time complexity. In naive way of using two loops for a and b and also incorporating the observation mentioned on last line of the question I was getting $O(p \sqrt{p})$. For you approach outer loop for k is p times and inner loop to factorise takes $O((p*p)^{1/4})$ if we used advanced factorisation like pollard rho.Overall time being the same $O(p \sqrt{p})$. Is my understanding correct? If so then we are back to square one.

Comment: Honestly I really can't.  It's my hope someone else will have a different approach.

Comment: Sure no issues. thanks for your contribution anyway. Your answer opened up few more ways to think. I am keeping it open to accept better approaches. The point is valid $k$ is dense in $[1,\sqrt{p}]$ but very sparse in range $[\sqrt{p},p+2]$ . So it would be stupid to traverse linearly for every $k \in [\sqrt{p},p-1]$ .